# Plotting an association key corresponding to the maximum value

Tags: plotting, associations, piecewise

I have an Association `<|0->q^2, 1->2p q, 2->p^2|>`, where `q=1-p`.
I would like to plot the key (0, 1 or 2) corresponding to the greatest value, as a piecewise function of `p`, where `p` is between 0 and 1.

This is what I have tried:

```
assoc=<|0->q^2, 1->2p q, 2->p^2|>;
keys=Keys[assoc];
values=Values[assoc];
optimalkey=keys[[Position[values,Max[values]][[1,1]]]];
Plot[Evaluate[optimalkey/.q->1-p],{p,0,1}]
```

This causes the error messages "Part 1 of {} does not exist", and several repetitions of "The expression {}[[1,1]] cannot be used as a Part specification."

However, I notice that

```
assoc=<|0->q^2, 1->2p q, 2->p^2|>;
keys=Keys[assoc];
values=Values[assoc];
optimalvalue=Max[values];
Plot[Evaluate[optimalvalue/.q->1-p],{p,0,1}]
```

produces a nice plot of a piecewise polynomial function, as expected and without generating any errors.

Please can anyone help ?

Comment: `Plot[keys[[Position[values /. q -> 1 -p,  Max[values /.q -> 1 -p]]
[[1, 1]]]], {p, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: or. `Plot[With[{vals=values/. q->1-p},keys[[Position[vals, Max[vals]][[1,1]]]]],{p,0,1}]`?

Comment: or, `optimalkey[v_] := keys[[Position[v, Max[v]][[1, 1]]]];
Plot[With[{p=p,q=1-p},optimalkey[values]]
, {p, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Thank you very much kglr !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
optimalkey=keys[[Position[values,Max[values]][[1,1]]]];
```

`Max` cannot return a *value* because `values` are expressions involving `p` and `q`; they are *symbols* with no values stored in them hence `Max` returns unevaluated. What that means is that when `Position` uses its second argument, it cannot match *anything* in `values` (since it is devoid of an expression with head `Max`) so it returns `{}`. In turn, `{}[[1,1]]` generates the error message, reported in the question.

On the other hand, plotting `Max[values]`, on the second code block, *does not* produce exactly what is expected. Like in the previous case, `Max` does not return a value, so plotting simply uses the monomials in the input association.

```
Block[{p,q},
   With[{assoc=<|0->q^2, 1->2p q, 2->p^2|>}, 
      getMax[pval_]:=Max[assoc/.{q->1-pval,p->pval}]
    ]
  ]
```

`getMax` should provide the desired values.

Note: the second code block in the question, probably returns the correct output.

Comment: Many thanks, yosimitsu !